# Formula that returns true or false when 1 value from a list of values meets a condition

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am looking for a formula that returns true or false when 1 value from a list of values meets a condition.

```
List:
100
200
300
400

=If(List>350;true;false)
```

The last value of the list is bigger than 350, output formula must be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your condition will always be `>` you can simply use MAX:

```
=IF(MAX(A1:A4) > 350, TRUE, FALSE)
```

If the condition is `<` you can use MIN in the same way.

If the condition might be something more complex, like "the list contains at least one value that is between 300 and 400", you'll need to use COUNTIF:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A4,">=300")-COUNTIF(A1:A4,">=400") > 0, TRUE, FALSE)
```

If you need *exactly one* value in that range, rather than *at least one*, then change the `> 0` to be `= 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the IF statements.

=MAX(A1:A4) > 350

Gives you the same results.

Comment: Hi Eric, welcome to SO - I think your answer might have been better posted as a comment on my answer, since I think you are referring to my suggestion with your change. Have a read of the FAQ here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work

Comment: Doh, sorry, having read my own link I realise you need 50 reputation to comment.